# AssertionError: col should be Column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to create a new column in PySpark and fill this column with the date of today?

This is what I tried:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
df = df.withColumn("date", str(now)[:10])
```

I get this error:

> AssertionError: col should be Column

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> How to create a new column in PySpark and fill this column with the date of today?

There is already function for that:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date

df.withColumn("date", current_date().cast("string"))
```

> AssertionError: col should be Column

Use literal

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df.withColumn("date", lit(str(now)[:10]))
```

Comment: Understood why the first example didn't work, but didn't understand why the second one (the one with lit) works.

Comment: @jason Because [`lit` returns `Column`](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-stubs/blob/f5f2de1ea263fb08591cd327450c0dce14f9131d/third_party/3/pyspark/sql/functions.pyi#L186)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,lit
users_list = [(1, 'Scott'), (2, 'Donald'), (3, 'Mickey'), (4, 'Elvis')]
now = datetime.datetime.now()
df = spark.createDataFrame(users_list, 'user_id int, user_first_name string')
df.select("user_id", "user_first_name").withColumn("date", lit(datetime.datetime.now())).show()
```