# Create new column in Pyspark Dataframe by filling existing Column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to create new column in an existing Pyspark DataFrame. Currently the DataFrame looks as follows:

```
+----+----+---+----+----+----+----+
|Acct| M1D|M1C| M2D| M2C| M3D| M3C|
+----+----+---+----+----+----+----+
|   B|  10|200|null|null|  20|null|
|   C|1000|100|  10|null|null|null|
|   A| 100|200| 200| 200| 300|  10|
+----+----+---+----+----+----+----+
```

I want to fill null values in column `M2C` with `0` and create a new column `Ratio`. My expected output would be as follows:

```
+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+-------+
| Acct |  M1D | M1C |  M2D |  M2C |  M3D |  M3C | Ratio |
+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+-------+
|    B |   10 | 200 | null | null | 20   | null |     0 |
|    C | 1000 | 100 | 10   | null | null | null |     0 |
|    A |  100 | 200 | 200  | 200  | 300  | 10   |   200 |
+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

I was trying to achieve my desired results by using following lines of code.

```
df = df.withColumn('Ratio', df.select('M2C').na.fill(0))
```

The above line of code resulted in an `assertion error` as shown below.

```
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

The possible solution that I found using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903905/assertionerror-col-should-be-column) was to use `lit` function.
I changed my code to

```
df = df.withColumn('Ratio', lit(df.select('M2C').na.fill(0)))
```

The above code led to `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`

How can I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing two things wrong here.

1. `df.select` will return a dataframe, not a column.
2. `na.fill` will replace null values in all columns, not just in specific columns.

The following code snippet will solve your usecase

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = df.withColumn('Ratio', col('M2C')).fillna(0, subset=['Ratio'])
```