# Pass date string into withColumn

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark and want to add a `yyyy_mm_dd` string to my DataFrame as a column, I have tried doing it like this:

```
end_date = '2020-01-20'
final = (
    df1
    .join(df, on = ['id', 'product'], how = 'left_outer')
    .where((sf.col('id').isNotNull()))
    .withColumn('status', when(sf.col('count') >= 10, 3)
    .when((sf.col('count') <= 9) & (sf.col('count') >= 1), 2)
    .when(sf.col('count').isNull(), 1))
    .withColumn('yyyy_mm_dd', end_date)
)
final.fillna(0, subset=['count']).orderBy('id', 'product').show(500,False)
```

This works without the last `.withColumn`, but I run into the below error when I include it:

> AssertionError: col should be Column

From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.withColumn), it seems I should be passing in a `col` as the second parameter to `withColumn`. Though, I'm unsure how to convert my date string to type `col`. I saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903905/assertionerror-col-should-be-column) from another post but I don't want to use `current_date()` since my `end_date` var will be read in from a coordinator script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lit`:

```
.withColumn('yyyy_mm_dd', sf.lit(end_date))
```

If you want a date type, you can cast accordingly:

```
.withColumn('yyyy_mm_dd', sf.lit(end_date).cast("date"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check with_column documentation.
It get the column name as first arg and a type of col as a second arg. You can use lit() to turn you string to a col
With a const value.

pyspark.sql.functions.lit(col)
Creates a Column of literal value.

> > > df.select(lit(5).alias('height')).withColumn('spark_user', lit(True)).take(1)
> > > [Row(height=5, spark_user=True)]