# AssertionError: col should be Column, on an type 'str' column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to PySpark and I'm trying to run the following code which replaces a `name` column with fake names.

```
# !pip install Faker
from faker import Faker
from functools import partial

def synthetic_column(string, faker_function):
  return faker_function()

partial_func = partial(synthetic_column, faker_function = Faker().first_name)

spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('name',partial_func(col('name')))

display(spark_df)
```

Yields `AssertionError: col should be Column`

I'm running the same code on an integer type column and I don't get this `AssertionError`,

Why is this happening? I have tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903905/assertionerror-col-should-be-column) but they aren't helpful.

*Please Advise.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply directly a python function to your dataframe. You need to transform it to UDF. But, in your case, you probably also need to install Faker on all your nodes because UDFs are executed on local executor env, and they need to be able to do the imports on local.

But once installed, your code just need to import `udf` and apply it to your faker function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

partial_func = udf(Faker().first_name)

df = df.withColumn("Name", partial_func())
```