# How Can I find all the Null fields in Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am trying to find out the null fields present in a dataframe and concatenate all the fields in a new field in the same dataframe.

Input dataframe looks like this

| name | state | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | CA | 100 |
| Julia | Null | Null |
| Null | CA | 200 |

Expected Output

| name | state | number | Null Fields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | CA | 100 |  |
| Julia | Null | Null | state,number |
| Null | CA | 200 | name |

My code looks like this but it is failing. Please help me here.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
data2 = [("James","CA","100"),
("Julia",None,None),
(None,"CA","200")]

schema = StructType([ \
StructField("name",StringType(),True), \
StructField("state",StringType(),True), \
StructField("number",StringType(),True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
cols = ["name","state","number"]
df.show()

def null_constraint_check(df,cols):
 df_null_identifier = df.withColumn("NULL Fields",\
                                    [F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c)) for c in cols])
 return df_null_identifier
df1 = null_constraint_check(df,cols)
```

Error I am getting

```
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AssertionError: col should be Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903905/assertionerror-col-should-be-column)

Comment: No @NathanLiang, it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct, you only have to make a small change in `null_constraint_check`:
`[F.count(...)]` is a list of columns and [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html) expects a single column as second parameter. One way to get there is to concatenate all elements of the list using [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html):

```python
def null_constraint_check(df,cols):
    df_null_identifier = df.withColumn("NULL Fields",
                         F.concat_ws(",",*[F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c) for c in cols]))
    return df_null_identifier
```

I have also removed the `F.count` because your question says that you want the names of the null columns.

The result is:

```
+-----+-----+------+------------+
| name|state|number| NULL Fields|
+-----+-----+------+------------+
|James|   CA|   100|            |
|Julia| null|  null|state,number|
| null|   CA|   200|        name|
+-----+-----+------+------------+
```